# Chamada de API retornando dados atrasados

Tags: flutter, dart

O que há de errado em minha função? Pois, os dados chamados na segunda api retornam com bastante atraso.

Como faço para a tela ser carregada somente após o retorno da segunda API?

```
var os = new List<OS>();

  _getOs() {
    API.getOS().then((response) {
      setState(() {
        Map<String, dynamic> data = json.decode(response.body);

        os = List<OS>.from(data['registros'].map((x) => OS.fromJson(x)));

        for (var i = 0; i < os.length; i++) {
          API.getCliente(os[i].idCliente).then((response) {
            var clies = new List<Cliente>();

            Map<String, dynamic> dataCli = json.decode(response.body);
            clies = List<Cliente>.from(
                dataCli['registros'].map((x) => Cliente.fromJson(x)));

            os[i].nomeCliente = clies[0].fantasia;
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Para carregar a parte do layout que deseja, após as chamadas da API existe algumas maneiras, vou lhe dar o exemplo de uma e então você tenta aplicar para o seu caso (Já que não nos deu muita informação).

Você pode utilizar o `FutureBuilder`, que ao construir o layout ele irá esperar a API retornar algum valor e então constrói o que precisa.

> Para ter o resultado esperado, utilizando o `FutureBuilder`, é necessário utilizar o `await` ao invés do `then()`

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  
   Future<List<OS>> _getOs() async {
     var os = new List<OS>();
     final responseOS = await API.getOS();
     
     Map<String, dynamic> data = json.decode(responseOS.body);

     setState(() {
       os = List<OS>.from(data['registros'].map((x) => OS.fromJson(x)));
     });

     for (var i = 0; i < os.length; i++) {
       final responseCliente = await API.getCliente(os[i].idCliente);
       var clies = new List<Cliente>();

       Map<String, dynamic> dataCli = json.decode(responseCliente.body);
       clies = List<Cliente>.from(
       dataCli['registros'].map((x) => Cliente.fromJson(x)));

       os[i].nomeCliente = clies[0].fantasia;
     }
     
     return os;
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _getOs(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<OS>> snapshot) {
        //Enquanto não existir nenhum valor retornado
        if (!snapshot.hasData)
          return Center(child: Text("Carregando dados"));

        // Quando existir dados a serem exibidos
        return Container(
          // child: Coloque aqui dentro sua estrutura atual, utilize a propriedade snapshot[n] para pegar os itens da lista retornada.
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

*Obs.: Não estou com acesso ao Flutter no momento, pode existir alguns probleminhas no código.*

Você pode ler mais sobre aqui [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).